# Can one tell which way the market goes from sell and buy orders?

Tags: exchanges, api

Among other open access (i.e. public) data available in exchange API's are the open order books. They are given on exchange websites sorted by coin value. Is there a way to tell which way the market is going, as in up or down for a given pair, from sell and buy order books? 
If the only way is by taking two snapshots of these data, would that be a good way to do it, or is there a better way, using public API's?

Answer (score 1):

Market direction, as with any direction, only applies when you have more than a single data point.

So, the value of the trade at `t-1` compared to the value of the trade at `t` can tell you if the market moved "up" or "down".  The value of `t`, by itself can only ever tell you the value of `t`.  There is no way to determine direction or velocity from a single point value.

If an individual API provides direction, then you could use that; however that is up to the individual API to provide.

Answer (score 0):

All you're seeing in the order book are offers to trade at specific prices. There's no commitment there; they can be easily added or removed at a moment's notice. That leaves the order book as a very weak and gameable indication of future market price movement.